# Filter Contact Records based on user's allowed companies in multi-companies

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14, record-rules

I am trying to filter a record according to user's allowed company  that will display  in Contacts. Any idea on how to accomplish it? Thanks in advance. I highly appreciate your answer/suggestions in advance.
Ex. User has allowed companies: Company A and Company B
Records with this kind of companies should only be displayed.

```
<record id="rule_custom_user_contacts" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name"> Record for CUstom Users Only</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner" />
        <field name="domain_force">['|',('company_id','!=', False),('company_id','=', user.company_id.id)]</field>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="True" />
        <field name="perm_write" eval="False" />
        <field name="perm_create" eval="False" />
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False" />
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('mymdule.group_custom_user'))]" />
    </record>
```

Comment: you tried `<field name="domain_force">['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id', 'in', company_ids)]</field>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better understand and trace the code I would suggest to define a function in res.partner model and return your domain there with any logic that you want so call it in your record rule, for doing that look at the sample

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'
 def set_contract_domain(self):
    #do any logic to get ids of user's companies and put it in user_companies_id  
    domain = [('company_id', 'in', user_companies_id)]
    return domain
```

and in xml file you have to call it like that:

```
<record id="user_access_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name"> Record for Custom Users Only</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_model_res_partner"/>
        <field name="global" eval="True"/>
        <field name="domain_force">user.env['res.partner'].set_contract_domain()</field>
    </record>
```

I hope it works for you :)